# Unable to use class from included header file

Tags: c++

Within Pair.h I have a Pair class.
Within Map.h I'm trying to do the following:

```
#include "pair.h"
template<class K, class V>
class Map {
public:
    //some stuff
private:

    class Node : public Pair {
        //some stuff
    };

};
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
./map.h:50:22: error: expected class name
        class Node : public Pair {
```

What I'm doing wrong?

[EDIT:]
Source code:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27412797/so_q_1/map.h
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27412797/so_q_1/pair.h

Comment: I don't see a #include "Pair.h"

Comment: Have you checked that you're using the exact same name? (Especially upper/lower case mismatch)

Comment: Does `pair.h` include `map.h`? If it does, then the circular dependency will cause this sort of error.

Comment: I do have include in my file, just forgot to copy it here.

Comment: pair. does not include map.h [or any other file]

Comment: can u post pair.h? or at least show how the class is declared

Comment: @Doppelganger: Perhaps we could see `pair.h`? (At least enough to reproduce the problem). It's difficult to guess what might be wrong without seeing it.

Comment: I will upload both files shortly.

Comment: Is `Pair` a template, perhaps? In that case, you probably want `Pair<K,V>`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, thanks this is indeed the problem. I'm still new c++ and templates, the syntax is very confusing to me...

Comment: Where is your [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that we've seen the definition of `Pair`:

```
template <class S, class T>
class Pair {
    //...
};
```

we see that it's a template; so you need to provide template arguments to instantiate a class from it:

```
class Node : public Pair<K,V> {
    //...
};
```